Inclusion of absorbing boundary in continuous stochastic process simulation
While I'm now aware of the great functions Mathematica has for simulating stochastic processes on an unbounded domain, a common problem is a bounded domain with absorbing boundaries. In particular, once the process hits the boundary it stays there forever.
Is there an elegant and efficient way to include absorbing boundaries into simulations such as the following. That is, to have the boundaries $(a,b)$ be absorbing?
\[Mu] = 1;
\[Theta] = 1;
\[Sigma] = 1;

{a, b} = {0, 4};

numreps = 10;
Tmax = 10;
dt = .1;


paths = Table[
   RandomFunction[
    ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[
        t] == \[Theta] (\[Mu] - 
          x[t])  \[DifferentialD]t + \[Sigma] \[DifferentialD]w[t], 
     x[t], {x, RandomReal[{a, b}]}, {t, 0}, 
     w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]], {0, Tmax, dt}], {i, numreps}];

ListLinePlot[paths, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {a - 1, b + 1}}, 
 GridLines -> {None, {a, b}}]



This solution works well
paths = Table[  
   Clip[RandomFunction[
     ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[
         t] == (\[Theta]  (\[Mu] - 
             x[t])   \[DifferentialD]t + \[Sigma]  \[DifferentialD]w[
             t])*UnitStep[(x[t] - a) (b - x[t])], 
      x[t], {x, RandomReal[{a, b}]}, {t, 0}, 
      w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]], {0, Tmax, dt}], {a, b}], {i, 
    numreps}];


Not sure it's elegant or efficient, but here's one possible way.
The original paths:
\[Mu] = 1; \[Theta] = 1; \[Sigma] = 1;
{a, b} = {0, 4};
numreps = 10; Tmax = 10; dt = .1;

SeedRandom[2];
paths = Table[RandomFunction[ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] == \[Theta]  (\[Mu] - 
          x[t])   \[DifferentialD]t + \[Sigma]  \[DifferentialD]w[t], 
     x[t], {x, RandomReal[{a, b}]}, {t, 0}, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]], {0, Tmax, dt}], {i, numreps}];

ListLinePlot[paths, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {a - 1, b + 1}}, GridLines -> {None, {a, b}}]


With paths staying at boundaries after they touch the first time:
abspaths =
  Table[
   t1 = p["Path"];
   firsthit = {SelectFirst[t1, #[[2]] <= a &, {Tmax, 0}], 
      SelectFirst[t1, #[[2]] >= b &, {Tmax, 0}]}[[All, 1]];
   ReplacePart[
    t1, {a_, 2} /; 
      a > Min[firsthit]/dt -> {b, a}[[RealSign[Subtract @@ firsthit]]]]
   , {p, paths}];

ListLinePlot[abspaths, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {a - 1, b + 1}}, GridLines -> {None, {a, b}}]



This certainly works well, but I will be scaling up the simulation. So I wonder if there is away to stop the process when it hits, rather than going back and editing the paths, with an eye to efficacy. But this is nice and appreciated !
